# All Kernel buffers have same address in all systems?

Tags: linux-kernel

Let's say the address of a buffer in my kernel is 0xB0E4. Do all other systems also have a kernel buffer in same address?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not.

A different kernel might not even have the buffer at all, much less at the same address.

If you restrict yourself to the exact same kernel binary, any dynamically created buffer could be at a different address from boot to boot.

If the buffer is static, then the offset is defined when the kernel is linked.  So the same kernel binary would have the buffer at the same offset.  If the kernel is not relocatable, then the address would be the same.  A relocatable kernel could still change from boot to boot, though the offset from the kernel start would be the same.

A module is run time linked when it is loaded, so a static buffer in a module will have different address depending on what memory was allocated to hold it.

What you might find at the same address is memory mapped IO  regions.  On many SoC systems these are at fixed addresses for a given device.